# Questions with both Ignored and Watched tags are styled in a way that draws visual attention

Tags: bug, design, question-lists, ignored-tags, tag-watching

Why do Ignored Tags not override the visual highlighted effect (where the background is a lighter color)?

If a question has tags that are both Ignored and Watched, I would expect that the question would be styled like a question that only includes Ignored tags (like last question in the image below).  Instead, the styling draws attention to the question because of the lighter background (like the second question in the image below), even though the title is a muted color.  This seems like a bug because I can't make sense of its purpose.

[image: questions]